# Angular Universal + Bootstrap document not defined

Tags: angular, angular-universal, ng-bootstrap, angular-ssr

Ive tried a lot of the hacks out there to bypass this error, my server.ts file looks as follows

```
import 'localstorage-polyfill'
import { existsSync } from 'fs'
import { join } from 'path'

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node'
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine'
import express from 'express'

import { createWindow } from 'domino'
const domino = require('domino');  // import the library `domino`
const indexHtml = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/my-app/browser/index.html')
const win = createWindow(indexHtml)
const win2 = domino.createWindow(indexHtml); // create object Window
global['window'] = win2;
global['Event'] = win2.Event;               // assign the `win.Event` to prop `Event`
global['document'] = win2.document;
// Polyfills
;(global as any).window = win;
;(global as any).document = win.document;
;(global as any).navigator = win.navigator;

(window as any).global = win;

global['localStorage'] = localStorage;
(global as any).localStorage = localStorage;

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';

import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common'

export function app(): express.Express {
  global['localStorage'] = localStorage;
  (window as any).global = win;
  global["document"] = win.document;  
  const server = express()
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/my-app/browser')
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html'))
    ? 'index.original.html'
    : 'index'
  
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html')
  server.set('views', distFolder)
  
  server.get(
    '*.*',
    express.static(distFolder, {
      maxAge: '1y'
    })
  )

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, {
      req,
      providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }]
    })
  })

  return server
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app()
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
}

declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main
const moduleFilename = (mainModule && mainModule.filename) || ''
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run()
}
export * from './src/main.server';
```

the exact error in the vendor.js file which is

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at enableDismissTrigger
```

and is related to bootstrap, this is the offending code:

```
const enableDismissTrigger = (component, method = 'hide') => {
  const clickEvent = `click.dismiss${component.EVENT_KEY}`;
  const name = component.NAME;
  EventHandler.on(document, clickEvent, `[data-bs-dismiss="${name}"]`, function (event) {
    if (['A', 'AREA'].includes(this.tagName)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    if (isDisabled(this)) {
      return;
    }
    const target = getElementFromSelector(this) || this.closest(`.${name}`);
    const instance = component.getOrCreateInstance(target); // Method argument is left, for Alert and only, as it doesn't implement the 'hide' method

    instance[method]();
  });
};
```

Im not sure how to get past this, I am doing the document polyfil in server like everyone suggests - my angular version is 15

Answer (score 0):

Use `Document` DI [token](https://angular.io/api/common/DOCUMENT) instead of global `document` it is SSR friendly

A DI Token representing the main rendering context. In a browser and SSR this is the DOM Document. When using SSR, that document is created by Domino.

```
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
@Component({...}) // could be a service too!
export class MyComponent {
 constructor (@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}


someMethod(){
const enableDismissTrigger = (component, method = 'hide') => {
const clickEvent = `click.dismiss${component.EVENT_KEY}`;
const name = component.NAME;
/// use injected document token
EventHandler.on(this.document, clickEvent, `[data-bs-dismiss="${name}"]`, function (event) {
 if (['A', 'AREA'].includes(this.tagName)) {
   event.preventDefault();
 }
 if (isDisabled(this)) {
   return;
 }
 const target = getElementFromSelector(this) || this.closest(`.${name}`);
 const instance = component.getOrCreateInstance(target); // Method argument is left, for Alert and only, as it doesn't implement the 'hide' method

 instance[method]();
});
};
}


}
```

Comment: Yeah, but he's probably just including the entire `bootstrap.js` file through html, so controlling that through angular will probably be tough